# Java servlet doPost method not working

Tags: java, html, forms, post, servlets

**Edit:**

I pointed the post request to /vault/Login but the servlet was on /vault/index and vault/login
when pointing it towards index it worked.

I'm trying to make a login system.
I have an html file which a post method is requested from but the doPost method is never fired when requested.
When the submit button is clicked the url changes with the parameters in it but nothing happens.
Every time the `doPost()` is executed the first statement writes something to the console but neither does that happen.

```
public class Login extends HttpServlet {



protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {


    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    System.out.println("fired");
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("loginFailed", false);


    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Login.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
}


@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("this is another test");            


    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    String username = (String)session.getAttribute("username");
    String password = (String)session.getAttribute("password");
    System.out.println(username + " " + password);
    boolean succes = false;

    if (!"".equals(username) && !"".equals(password)){
        try {
            succes = Authentication.checkCredentials(username, password);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    switch ((String)session.getAttribute("platform")){
        case "browser":
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Lobby.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
            break;
        case "desktop":

            int id = Tracker.getIdByUsername(username);
            List vaults = (List)VaultManagement.getVaultsByUserId(id);

            int[] vaultIds = new int[vaults.size()];

            if (vaults.isEmpty()){
                vaultIds[0] = -1;
            }else{
               int x = 0;
               for (Object vault : vaults){
                Vault v = (Vault)vault;
                vaultIds[x] = v.getId();

                x++;
               } 
            }
            DAL.Entities.Account account = AccountManagement.getAccountByUsername(username);
            LoginPackage pack = new LoginPackage(username, password, account.getEmail(), vaultIds);
            String json = JSON.dataPackageToJson(pack);
            PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
            writer.print(json);


            break;
    }

}

@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>
```

}

Post

```
<div class="jumbotron" width="10%">
            <form id="form"  action="/vault/Login.jsp">
                <h6>Username:</h6>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username">
                <h6>Password:</h6>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password"><br>
                <button type="button" onclick="location.href='vault/Register.jsp'" class="btn btn-secondary">Register</button>
                <input type="hidden" name="platform" value="browser"/> 
                <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
            </form>



        </div>
```

Comment: Why are you using `session.getAttribute`? Try `request.getParameter` to actually get the values from the **request**.

Comment: I'm new to Java, I just saw it somewhere and asummed it worked, I've changed it.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to specify the `method` attribute to be `post`:

```html
<form id="form"  action="/vault/Login.jsp" method="post">
<!-- Here ---------------------------------^ -->
```

Comment: Doesn't work, I used it previously but removed it again because when I specified the method it didn't change the url with the parameters so I thought it was wrong and removed it.
(I just tested it again)

Comment: @Jari A `post` request sends the parameters in the request's body, not in the URL.

Comment: Oh, I misinterpreted something I watched

Comment: The problem actually was the .jsp in the string